# You're on a date in a park in the evening, what should you avoid to ensure the proper yichud rules are addressed?

Tags: halacha, shidduchim-dating, yichud-seclusion

Yichud prohibits seclusion between a man and woman who are unrelated (roughly).

If a couple is on a shidduch and a park is the venue, what exactly makes the park problematic?

If the park has at least another single person is that enough?

I am looking for the exact criteria that would make the park permissible vs forbidden.

Comment: An empty highway is more problematic than a public park

Comment: The last time I studied the laws of yichud was years ago, but I believe from a purely halachic standpoint, as long as they are somewhere another person could appear without warning and there is some reasonable possibility that that might happen, they are not considered secluded. Nonetheless, propriety might dictate not going somewhere that is pretty isolated, even if it is not technically yichud.

Comment: RE your question "If the park has at least another single person is that enough?" If the person is a woman, then yes. Technically one woman in a room with even thousands of men is considered secluded though.

Comment: @Daniel, the other way around (_Rama_ 22:5, q.v.).

Comment: @msh210 of course you're right. Told you it had been a long time since I'd learned the halachas of yichud

Answer (score 1):

If at this park, at that time, it is common that people walk by and there is no block (such as locked passage etc) on the path that leads to it, and the spot at which the couple are is clearly visible, as in most cases of a public park, there is perfect compliance with the Yichud rules.

In many Ultra-Orthodox communities, one would not rely on a place where there is just a good chance that someone might walk by, but rather would pick a place where people always are present at the time, such as a popular park, hotel lobby, etc.